# Naoqi eventhandling 10 Secounds delay

Tags: python, event-handling, delay, led, nao-robot

I am working with a NAO-robot on a Windows-XP machine and Python 2.7.

I want to detect markers in speech. The whole thing worked, but unfortunately I have to face now a 10 Secounds delay and my events aren't detected (the callback function isnt invoked).

First, my main-function:

```
from naoqi import ALProxy, ALBroker
from speechEventModule import SpeechEventModule
myString = "Put that \\mrk=1\\ there."
NAO_IP = "192.168.0.105" 
NAO_PORT = 9559
memory = ALProxy("ALMemory", NAO_IP, NAO_PORT)
tts = ALProxy("ALTextToSpeech", NAO_IP, NAO_PORT)
tts.enableNotifications()

myBroker = ALBroker("myBroker",
   "0.0.0.0",   # listen to anyone
   0,           # find a free port and use it
   NAO_IP,         # parent broker IP
   NAO_PORT)       # parent broker port

global SpeechEventListener
SpeechEventListener = SpeechEventModule("SpeechEventListener", memory)
memory.subscribeToEvent("ALTextToSpeech/CurrentBookMark", "SpeechEventListener", "onBookmarkDetected")
tts.say(initialString)
```

And here my speechEventModule:

```
from naoqi import ALModule
from naoqi import ALProxy

NAO_IP = "192.168.0.105" 
NAO_PORT = 9559

SpeechEventListener = None
leds = None
memory = None

class SpeechEventModule(ALModule):
    def __init__(self, name, ext_memory):
        ALModule.__init__(self, name)
        global memory
        memory = ext_memory
        global leds 
        leds = ALProxy("ALLeds",NAO_IP, NAO_PORT)        

    def onBookmarkDetected(self, key, value, message):
        print "Event detected!"
        print "Key: ", key
        print "Value: " , value
        print "Message: " , message

        if(value == 1):
            global leds
            leds.fadeRGB("FaceLeds", 0x00FF0000, 0.2)
        if(value == 2):
            global leds
            leds.fadeRGB("FaceLeds", 0x000000FF, 0.2)
```

Please, do anybody have the same problem?
Can anybody give me an advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can exclude problems with overheating

Comment: You say it worked... what have you modified? Probably the module you have programmed takes a lot of CPU (here, only you can know why. Start thinking in the changes you have introduced when in started to fail). You can see if it is a CPU issue connecting to the robot using ssh and executing the 'top' command

Comment: Hello Manuel, thanks a lot for your reply! Yes, it worked last week, I am debugging, separated the eventhandling from the whole project to be sure to fix that problem. It was a good idea with the CPU, i connected via ssh to my nao, but there is no process which causes more than 10% of the cpu - so your suggestion was not the solution :(  but thx. Do you have more suggestions? Thx in advance my friend!

Comment: If tts detects a marker, it seems that it cant handle it and as I wrote, the callback function isnt invoked. To detect markers, we used the leds. I also tried my script with two other Naos. The problem must be on my side.

Comment: As the main problem is that the callback is not raised, maybe you should consider editing your question to make it more clear to others. Something like 'NAOqi: Callback not raised'. Anyway, you say you have a delay into the mark detection of 10 seconds and later say the callback is not raised... do not you think it sounds contradictory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subscribing to the event outside your module. if I am not wrong you have to do it into the `__init__` method.

```
class SpeechEventModule(ALModule):

    def __init__(self, name, ext_memory):
        ALModule.__init__(self, name)
        memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")
        leds = ALProxy("ALLeds")
```

Anyway, check that your main function keeps running forever (better if you catch a keyboard interruption) or you program will end before he can catch any keyword.

```
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print
    print "Interrupted by user, shutting down"
    myBroker.shutdown()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Take a look to [this tutorial](http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/python/reacting_to_events.html), it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it would be done with a more recent Naoqi version:

```
import qi
import argparse


class SpeechEventListener(object):
    """ A class to react to the ALTextToSpeech/CurrentBookMark event """

    def __init__(self, session):
        super(SpeechEventListener, self).__init__()
        self.memory = session.service("ALMemory")
        self.leds = session.service("ALLeds")
        self.subscriber = self.memory.subscriber("ALTextToSpeech/CurrentBookMark")
        self.subscriber.signal.connect(self.onBookmarkDetected)
        # keep this variable in memory, else the callback will be disconnected

    def onBookmarkDetected(self, value):
        """ callback for event ALTextToSpeech/CurrentBookMark """
        print "Event detected!"
        print "Value: " , value  # key and message are not useful here

        if value == 1:
            self.leds.fadeRGB("FaceLeds", 0x00FF0000, 0.2)
        if value == 2:
            self.leds.fadeRGB("FaceLeds", 0x000000FF, 0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--ip", type=str, default="127.0.0.1",
                        help="Robot IP address. On robot or Local Naoqi: use '127.0.0.1'.")
    parser.add_argument("--port", type=int, default=9559,
                        help="Naoqi port number")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Initialize qi framework
    connection_url = "tcp://" + args.ip + ":" + str(args.port)
    app = qi.Application(["SpeechEventListener", "--qi-url=" + connection_url])
    app.start()
    session = app.session
    speech_event_listener = SpeechEventListener(session)

    tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
    # tts.enableNotifications() --> this seems outdated
    while True:
        raw_input("Say something...")
        tts.say("Put that \\mrk=1\\ there.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to manually bind the callback, by doing so:

```
def __init__(self, name, ext_memory):
    ALModule.__init__(self, name)
    self.BIND_PYTHON( self.getName(),"onBookmarkDetected" );
```

It's what I do when using callback in some Choregraphe boxes.